# In Wagtail, are there any options to display a hero block with a video background?

Tags: video, wagtail

I'm redesigning a client's website that uses Wagtail, and it doesn't appear to support video uploads - only embeds. We'd like the option of creating hero blocks with video backgrounds, so are there any plugins that would achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3):

Typically hosting your own video isn't generally accepted to be a "good idea", but I understand the need for it.

There's a Torchbox created package called `wagtailmedia` that you can install. It gives you a document-like manager for video and audio files.

```
pip install wagtailmedia
```

Check out the full repo here: https://github.com/torchbox/wagtailmedia

Comment: Thanks very much. I will pass this on to my clients.

For my own understanding, why isn't it a good idea to host your own videos, specifically if they're just used as backgrounds? There are no playback controls needed, no editing tools... Just a moving image instead of a static image.

Comment: Self hosting videos means you're serving the end user a significantly larger file. Usually upwards to 5mb, but it might not be contained to a video that small. .mp4's have an option inside of them to start playing before the "table of contents" is downloaded, but it's usually turned off by default. So the user ends up downloading ~2+ mb before the video starts. Whereas YouTube and Vimeo use streaming settings to start playing right away and downloads as it goes, plus they use CDN's so the video can be served much faster for people who aren't living near your server. TLDR: Self hosting is slow.